# Variation in MD5sum for StringIO object vs saved file?

Tags: python, md5, python-imaging-library, cstring

I have a piece of python code, as follows:

```
def make_portrait(self, image_name):

    im = Image.open(str(image_name))

    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    im.save(output, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    self.portrait_md5 = hashlib.md5(output.getvalue()).hexdigest()
    output.close()
    self.portrait_asset = self.portrait_md5 + '.jpg'
    self.portrait_xml = '<net.rptools.maptool.model.Asset>\n  <id>\n    <id>' + self.portrait_md5 + \
                        '</id>\n  </id>\n  <name>' + self.name + \
                        '</name>\n  <extension>jpg</extension>\n  <image/>\n</net.rptools.maptool.model.Asset>\n'
    self.portrait = im
```

Its job is to read in a given image file, convert the image to JPG format at 70% quality, then calculate an MD5 checksum for the converted data.  Elsewhere in the program, the converted image data gets written out to an actual file on the disk, with an accompanying file containing metadata about it (such as the MD5 sum).

The code runs fine, but the check sums don't match the final output.  Suppose I feed it an image, it does the conversion, and comes up with "ce5d1126ba52ba1618c402a13bee1c0c" as the check sum.  If I later go examine the final file that gets saved to disk, md5sum says it has the check sum "bb5ae2fdfea6294267b7ffdc226e21fa" instead.

This is causing problems because the program that's supposed to use the file this code is generating checks the MD5 sum of the actual file and compares it to the MD5 sum reported in the metadata.  If the two don't match, it chokes.

I'm very new to Python.  How do I make it generate an MD5 sum that will match that of the image file that gets saved to disk?

Happy to provide additional details if needed.

Comment: where is the code to write to the file? You're throwing away `output`.

Comment: Honestly? I'm not sure. I thought it was just saving the data as a property of self to be written later by something somewhere else. I'm modifying an existing program ([hl2mt](http://hg.tarsis.org/hl2mt)) rather than starting from scratch, so there's quite a lot of code whose function I'm hazy on.

Comment: Then you cannot be sure you save the same file as you calculate the md5 sum of. Probably the JPEG contains a timestamp that gives another md5 if saved again.

Comment: See my comment below the answer below - it's not a time stamp, but a secondary conversion to PNG data that I failed to adjust, so I was winding up with a file claiming to be a JPG but actually containing PNG data.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming it is something to do with PIL writing the file because the md5 from a `StringIO()` and the file are the same as shown here:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> import hashlib
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> sample = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> data = "".join([random.choice(string.lowercase) for _ in range(10000)])
>>> sample.write(data)
>>> sample.seek(0)
>>> md5 = hashlib.md5()
>>> md5.update(sample.read())
>>> md5.hexdigest()
'1b0d867b8e5aa66de816285076b7d457'
>>> sample.seek(0)
>>> with open("as_file.txt", "w") as f:
...     f.write(sample.read())
...
>>> subprocess.call("md5 as_file.txt".split())
MD5 (as_file.txt) = 1b0d867b8e5aa66de816285076b7d457
```

Maybe try seeking to the beginning of the output before generating the hash.

```
im.save(output, "JPEG", quality=70)
output.seek(0)
self.portrait_md5 = hashlib.md5(output.getvalue()).hexdigest()
```

### EDIT

This is doing what I would expect, and is essentially the same as your code.  Where are you writing the file to disk?

```
from PIL import Image
import StringIO
import hashlib
import subprocess

im = Image.open("foo.png")
data = StringIO.StringIO()
im.save(data, "JPEG", quality=70)
md5 = hashlib.md5(data.getvalue()).hexdigest()
with open("foo.jpg", "w") as f:
    im.save(f, "JPEG", quality=70)

print md5
print subprocess.call("md5 foo.jpg".split())
```

### OUTPUT

```
e5954ce7fb4d22dfac63372bfc948903
MD5 (foo.jpg) = e5954ce7fb4d22dfac63372bfc948903
```

Comment: Ah, jeez.  I just went and tracked down the code that actually saves the file to disk.  I should have done that before asking - it was converting the output from JPG to PNG, so the end result was NOT the same data as it was when the portrait was initially made.  *facepalm* Sorry for asking without having done my debugging properly. :-/